# Why is this true: $P(X<a)=P(X^{2}<a^{2})$?

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable.

I know that it is true to do the following $P(X<a)=P(X^{2}<a^{2})$.
What I don't know is why this is true. Could you please help me.

Comment: $X^2<a^2 \iff -a<X<a$. So what you say is true if $X\geq 0$ but may be false otherwise.

Comment: Thats not the case every time for example               $f(x)=1/2, ~if~ x=-1;~and~f(x)=1/2,~if~x=1$ then

$P\left( {X <  - 1} \right) = 0$ but $P\left( {{X^2} < 1} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and let $a=-1$.
Then $P(X<a)=0$ while $P(X^2<a^2)=1$.
Therefore your claim is false.

On the other hand, if we suppose $P(X < 0)=0$ and $a>0$ then your claim is true. That's because 
$$P(X^2<a^2) = P(-a<X<a) = P(-a<X 
< 0) + P(0 \leq X<a) = P(X<a).
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general that $\Pr(X<a)=\Pr(X^2<a^2)$.  It is true if $X$ is a non-negative random variable, i.e. $\Pr(X\ge0)=1$.

If $X$ has a standard normal distribution, i.e. distributed according to the standard "bell-shaped curve", then $\Pr(X^2<a^2)=\Pr(-a<X<a)$, if $a\ge0$.  The reason why those two probabilities are equal is simply that $X^2<a^2$ if and only if $-a<X<a$.  For example, if you square numbers between $-3$ and $+3$ you get numbers less than $9$, since $9$ is $3^2$ and $9$ is $(-3)^2$.